# Cloning still refusing even after creating an ssh key and saving it on my github account

Tags: clone

So the issue here is failing to clone my repository into visual studio code even after creating a key.
This is the error it's giving me

> Permission denied (public key).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

At first it told me to create a key. I did that but cloning still refusing. And I also followed some rules on how to add the key to the agent but however the steps where confusing.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you add tags and explanation about what is happening to you? Is it an issue with Git? What do you execute, what does it respond? Have you few logs?

Comment: How are you trying to clone your GitHub repository? Are you doing it from some webpage? Or are you doing it from a terminal window, i.e. issuing a `git clone` command? If from a webpage, then can you post a link to that page? If from a terminal, then post the actual command that you tried.